# How to create a class that's extended with a Mongoose Document type

Tags: typescript, mongoose

I have setup my application to use Mongoose to write to a MongoDB database and it works fine. Now, I am trying to add some tests and I am having trouble instantiating a mockup class to use in the test.

Here is the code to my document.

```
import { Document } from 'mongoose';
import { Prop, Schema, SchemaFactory } from '@nestjs/mongoose';
import { IsString, IsOptional, ValidateNested } from 'class-validator';

@Schema()
export class Group extends Document {
  @Prop()
  @IsString()
  readonly id: string;
  @Prop()
  @IsString()
  readonly name: string;
  @Prop({ type: Map})
  @ValidateNested()
  readonly properties?: Object;

  public static of(params: Partial<Group>): Group {
    const group = new Group();
    Object.assign(group, params);
    return group;
  }
}

export const GroupSchema = SchemaFactory.createForClass(Group);
```

I am using the `of` method to make it easier to instantiate a class in the test file.

Here is what I am using in the test file:

```
 const fakeGroup: Group = Group.of({
    id: "1",
    name: "admins",
    properties: {
      plan: "free"
    }
  });
```

Should work fine as I used this in other applications. But in the past apps, the class did not extend from Document. So, now, when I try to run the test, I am confronted with this error:

**TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'tree')**

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to work around this by using a different approach in my class definition:

```
export type GroupDocument = Group & Document;
```

Which allowed me to instantiate Group separately.

Answer (score 0):

For people who want to use the Mongoose solution,
I suggest this one.

```
import { HydratedDocument } from 'mongoose';

export type GroupDocument = HydratedDocument<Group>;
```